# I don't see printed results with SSHv2 subsystem

Tags: c, linux, ssh

I am trying to create an SSH subsystem.
So I configured the file : "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" by adding this line: "Subsystem test /home/test".

And here is the content of the test app:

```
int main()
{
        int i=0;
        int j=0;

        printf("Hello world!\n");
        for (j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            scanf ("%d",&i);
            printf ("Printed :   %d\n",i);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

My problem that when I execute this from a remote ssh connexion( ssh -2 -s test user@host ) I can only enter data and I can't see the printed text. (the text will be printed only after the application reach the end)

How can fix that to see the printed text after i enter it not in the end of the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a buffering question? Try calling `fflush()` to flush output.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    printf("Hello world!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        scanf ("%d",&i);
        printf ("Printed :   %d\n",i);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```